# can i get replies for a certain tweet using codebird in php?

Tags: api, twitter

can i get replies for a certain tweet using codebird in php?
iam trying to get any inserted tweet replies by its ID. is there a way?!
thank you

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey($ConsumerKey, $ConsumerSecret);
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken($AccessToken, $AccessTokenSecret);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the legacy standard Twitter API v1.1 there's no way to easily find replies to a Tweet. The v2 Twitter recent search API does provide the ability to search for Tweets by "conversation ID" (i.e. the ID of the parent Tweet), but at the time of posting this response to your question, Codebird does not support v2.